# Changing Card Values based on Selected Date

Tags: powerbi

I have a history of financial metrics for clients and I also have a dropdown to select which reporting period I want the data to display. I would like to have a card that displays the credit metric change with the date selected. The problem is that it's giving me the average of all periods and I just want the most current period.

Comment: Please give us the information of your relevant table(s) structure with some data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar report to yours.

I would create a measure representing the current value based on the period selected in your filter visual:

```
Measure = AVERAGEX('Table','Table'[Column])
```